# How do i delete an json element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, http

So I'm using a REST sandbox API to delete a "Call" from a state array, and the array contains all JSON not sure what to use to remove it.

Do note: This is connecting through HTTP from a Lua Script ran Request.

Website: getsandbox.com

Here's the code:

```js
//Store Calls
state.calls = state.calls || []
var calls = state.calls;



/*
|
| Create Call
V
*/

Sandbox.define('/new/call/','POST', function(req, res){
    
    var gameid = req.get("Roblox-Id");
    var person = req.body.split(" ")[0];
    var reason = req.body.split(" ")[1];
    var comp = {
        gameid: gameid,
        player: person,
        callreason: reason
    };
    
    calls.push(comp);
    // Set the type of response, sets the content type.
    res.type('text/plain');
    
    // Set the status code of the response.
    res.status(200);
    
    // Send the response body.
    res.send('Request Accepted');
});

/*
|
| Get Calls
V
*/

Sandbox.define('/get/calls/','GET', function(req, res){
    // Check the request, make sure it is a compatible type
    
    // Set the type of response, sets the content type.
    res.type('application/json');
    
    // Set the status code of the response.
    res.status(200);
    
    // Send the response body.
    res.send(calls);
})

/*
|
| Delete
v
*/

Sandbox.define('/data/delete/{gameid}/','GET', function(req, res){
    for(i=0;i<calls.length;i++){
        calls[i].pop();
    }
    
    // Set the type of response, sets the content type.
    res.type('text/plain');
    
    // Set the status code of the response.
    res.status(200);
    
    // Send the response body.
    res.send('Successful');
})
```

Comment: I think you may have meant `calls.pop();`, although "it won't let me" doesn't really tell me what part of the code isn't working.

Comment: how are you identifying the element that requires deletion/removal? the value of a sub key? where in your supplied code are your attempting to remove elements? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `index` of the `call` and use the following:

```
calls.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: How would i indexOf it if it contains JSON

Comment: @Dubst3p you could use `JSON.parse(jsonData)` to convert the json text into javascript object and search through it.